Is there a way to make spark-bigquery-connector faster?
I'm trying to use spark-bigquery-connector to load data from a sql query into a dataset and perform my manipulations, in Java. Using the bigquery java client gets me the results back in about 2 seconds. For the same query, it takes about 4.5 seconds for the spark connector.
Here is my code:
spark = SparkSession.builder()
                        .appName("test")
                        .config("spark.master", "local")
                        .config("spark.jars.packages", "com.google.cloud.spark:spark-3.5-bigquery:0.39.0")
                        .getOrCreate();

                
spark.conf().set("temporaryGcsBucket", "test_bucket");
spark.conf().set("viewsEnabled", "true");
spark.conf().set("materializationDataset", "dtc");


Dataset<Row> testDF = spark.read().format("bigquery")
                .option("query", sql)
                .option("enableReadSessionCaching", true)
                .option("readDataFormat", "AVRO")
                .load()
                .persist();


Anything I can do to make this faster? I don't want to use the bigquery client as it gives me back a Tableresult, an iterable class, and I'd rather use a dataset to achieve what I want, but speed is a factor I need to consider. The sql query is only retrieving about 400 rows of data after the filtering it does and I know spark is better suited for much larger datasets, but I'm wondering if I can get it to be more performant for this case too.
